# Get the selected control of a TabControl, not the content

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a simple application that mainly consists of a TabControl and a StatusBar with an Slider. Each tab hosts an custom control that can be zoomed in & out. The slider in the status bar should give the user the abillity to zoom in & out the content of the currently selected tab. My problem is that I'am unable to assign the sliders value to the currently selected custom control.

Here's the xaml of my TabControl:

```
    <TabControl x:Name="MyTabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <controls:MyControl x:Name="foo" DataContext="{Binding}">
                 </controls:MyControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

For the slider I want something like this, but it should be bound to the "foo.bar" property of the currently selected tab:

```
     <Slider
         Value="{Binding ElementName=foo, Path=bar}">
     </Slider>
```

Is that possible or is there a better way to use a Slider to adjust and display a property of the currently selected custom control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding a `Value` property to the class (or classes) that are set as the `DataContext` for each `TabItem`. Then you could data bind the `Slider.Value` property to the `Value` property in the data item from the selected `TabItem` using the `TabControl.SelectedItem` property. Try this:

```
<Slider Value="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.Value, ElementName=MyTabControl}" />
```

Comment: Hm, isn't that what I already have (more or less)? The problem is that the objects in the datacontext ("MyItems") are images for example. It does not make much sense to add a property "zoom" to an image. I'd rather set the desired zoom on the "MyControl". Isn't there a way to get the selected TabItem from the TabControl? That way I could maybe create an custom TabItem where I can set the zoom (or any other proeprty) in general...

Comment: *It does not make much sense to add a property "zoom" to an image*... no it doesn't. But it does make sense to put your `MyItems` collection property into a class along with a `Value` property and then set an instance of *that class* as the `DataContext`... perhaps you should read up about view models, as that is effectively what you'd have.